# "ERROR: Get "https://gcr.io/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" In docker for windows OS

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I am trying to setup an application which is having python and graph QL as backend and is using radis, while building nginx
using

```
'
 docker-compose --profile backend --profile frontend  up --build
'
```

it is pulling radis and then getting failed with

**ERROR- Get "https://gcr.io/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.**

**I am using it on windows**,

I tried by two ways-

1 Placing file in "Programdata\Docker\config\daemon.json" which is having below content,

```
'
{
"insecure-registries" : [ "your.registry.host:5000" ]
}
'
```

2. Adding content in  C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json

   '
   {
   "insecure-registries" : [ "your.registry.host:5000" ]
   }
   '

But no luck, Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi Amey and wecome on SO. You must change your.registry.host by `gcr.io`. However gcr.io certificate is emitted by Google Trust Services LLC which is a well known Authority. Can you check by going on https://gcr.io/v2/ if your browser raises an alert about the cert.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution update your docker-compose.yml script with google/<docker_name> instead of gcr.io

For example:

```
cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
```

To

```
cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:latest
```